# Gstreamer H264 pipeline lag

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

I am using [gst-rtsp-server](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-rtsp-server/) with the following pipeline:

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory, "( "
    "appsrc name=mysrc "
    "! videoconvert " 
    "! videoscale "
    "! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=350,height=250 " // fps
    "! x264enc bitrate=128 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=4 key-int-max=15 intra-refresh=true "
    "! video/x-h264,profile=baseline "
    "! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 mtu=1300 "
")");
```

to transmit an H264 video stream (I am entirely new to gstreamer). I'm running in push mode:

```
g_object_set(appsrc, "stream-type", GST_APP_STREAM_TYPE_STREAM, NULL);
```

and only pushing via the need-data callback. Mostly everything is working as expected. When I run my server - my cameras stream fine, except that my stream is experiencing a 2 second (approx) lag.

This lag is consistent regardless of any combination of settings I use.

Different

- bit rates
- camera resolutions
- running at 4 fps: `GST_BUFFER_DURATION(buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int(1, GST_SECOND, 4);`
- running at 30 fps: `GST_BUFFER_DURATION(buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int(1, GST_SECOND, 30);`

all have the same effect. It's like my stream accumulates an exact 2 seconds of lag and is permanently offset since. As if gstreamer were accumulating its internal buffer to a specific size before beginning to broadcast it.

Because of my inexperience with gstreamer I'm flat out stumped on this. If anyone had any ideas or hints to point me in *some* direction to continue debugging this it would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT:

For completeness (in case anyone else relates to this question), after @peter 's direction, I had to modify my pipeline to accommodate VLCs now smaller buffer. I don't know if this is "the correct way", but it worked for me.

I basically made my "producer" (my program) produce at 60fps and scale it down to 30fps for transmission in the pipeline using the `videorate` module. With this I was able to give VLC a 200ms buffer. This is my new pipeline.

```
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory, "( "
    "appsrc name=mysrc "
    "! videoconvert " 
    "! videoscale "
    "! videorate "
    "! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=350,height=250,framerate=30/1 " // fps
    "! x264enc bitrate=128 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true threads=4 key-int-max=15 intra-refresh=true "
    "! video/x-h264,profile=baseline "
    "! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 mtu=1300 "
")");
```

Thanks again to @peter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sender might be 100% fine.  If I were a gambling man, I'd bet the issue is on the receiver.

Some receivers (like VLC) will want to buffer up video to try to prevent stuttering.  I would look through the options on your receiver to turn down these options if possible if your goal is less latency.

Edited to add:

Check this out: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/change-vlc-streaming-buffer/
By default, VLC has a 1500ms (1.5s) cache.

Comment: @peter Pete, you are the man my friend (and I even forgot to mention that the receiver I was using was indeed VLC), thank you. I've been scratching my head about this for a few days now. I wish I could do more than type thank you - * sheds a tear * - Thank you!